# Tsung Getting Crashed at the end of test and tsung.log getting zero

Tags: performance, erlang, performance-testing, tsung

While running the Tsung test, values are getting captured in `Tsung.log`, but as the test is going to end just before that it goes to zero (0) byte and gives error in `tsung_controller@hostname.log` as follows:

```
** Reason for termination ==
** {terminated,[{io,format,
                    [<0.56.0>,"statsenter code here: ~p ~p ~p~n",
                     [size_rcv,22411275,1143859200]],`enter code here`
```

Can anyone help me out here.

Comment: There is not enough information in this question to answer it.

Comment: During execution we are able to see the results are being captured in the respective Tsung.log but as test going towards end and just before the end it clears the all the results log. if we have test duration let say 30 min...till 29 min we are able to see the results are in "tsung.log" also in other tsung logs but as close to 30 min it suddenly become empty files at around 29 min 55 sec.